# «Сейчас же впотьмах лесная чащоба словно вымерла»

Tags: орфография

> Сейчас же впотьмах лесная чащоба словно вымерла, все всерьез приготовились к ночи ― поре покоя и тишины.

Почему в конце слова *вымерла* стоит буква *а*?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Answer (score 4):

Сейчас же, впотьмах, лесная **чащоба** словно **вымерла**, все всерьез приготовились к ночи ― поре покоя и тишины.

Чащоба словно вымерла (ж.р.)., окончание А.

Comment: А что насчет запятых? Сейчас же(,) впотьмах(,)  лесная чащоба словно вымерла...

Comment: Нужна запятая, это уточняющее обстоятельство (когда стемнело). "Днем (по)всюду ....царила шумная жизнь. Сейчас же, впотьмах, лесная чащоба словно вымерла..

Answer (score 4):

[**чащоба**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/265490/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0), *ж*.
Лесная чаща, густая заросль чего-либо.

ВЫ́МЕРЕТЬ, вымерла (ж. р., прош. вр., совер. к *вымирать*).

Чащоба (что сделал**а**?) словно вымерл**а**.
[Глаголы прошедшего времени в форме единственного числа изменяют окончания по родам: мужской род — окончание нулевое,  женский род — А, средний род — окончание О.]

*У древней дороги **чащоба редела**: тут и там виднелись просветы и даже небольшие полянки.*
А. Ливадный. Последний из Бессмертных

*Со всех сторон девушку **окружала чащоба**, но совершенно не мрачная, хотя лес был довольно густой.*
М. Надеждина. Пропавшая без вести